# Unable to upload certain image to TinyPic

Tags: tinypic

I'm trying to upload a certain image to http://tinypic.com/ but it always says the image has been moved or deleted. No problems with any other image.

The picture is [this](http://nansupport.com/images/touchstone-mobile/tchmbl-otg-cable-1180x872b.png).

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on Google and found out that this is a very common issue.

Many TinyPic users have complained that their images were randomly deleted and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyPic) TinyPic blocked site access to users from Argentina.

But since TinyPic is owned by Photobucket, maybe [this thread](https://www.rcsparks.com/forum/threads/this-image-or-video-has-been-moved-or-deleted-photobucket-images-not-displaying.266/) can help. They are talking about a similar problem in Photobucket that can be solved by generating a URL with no spaces.

You can also consider using some other tools for image uploading like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload) that store your images in the cloud utilizing Amazon's S3 service and also provide secure backups for your images, so no risk of loosing your pictures.

Comment: If you buy Photobucket premium do they preserve your tinypic pictures?

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2019, Tinypic [is shutting down](http://tinypic.com/):

> Due to an inability to support a high-quality free digital service that derives 100% of its revenue from ever declining on-site revenues, TinyPic will be permanently shutting down on September 16, 2019. Because we want to give you as much notice and information as possible during our transition, [please carefully review the following information](http://tinypic.com/).

So, **September 16, 2019, is the last day one would be able to access images**.